# Leaflet check if L.geoJSON layer has any features

Tags: leaflet

I am making my own layer control in a way.
I want to check if a named L.geoJSON has any features. If not I will fetch GeoJSON from an API and add it to the layer.

But I cannot work out how to check if it has any feature?
Have tried to find someway around it, have been trying to look for properties on the object, but cannot get it to work.

```
const mygeojsonLayer= L.geoJSON(null)

if(mygeojsonLayer._layers.length === 0){
        mygeojsonLayer.addTo(map)
} else {fetchData()}
```

Comment: GeoJSON layer is a group layer, so you could use `getLayers()` method to check if it contains any layers/features.

Comment: Thats right! Tha should work. Thaks!